# Calculate sum for entire sheet based on hours

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet that has various weekly hours against a fixed number. For example

```
Name     Weekly Hours     Week 1  Week 2  Week 3

Jon                40        44     36     40  
Shaun              40        40     36     44  
Dawn               20        25     10     16
```

Is there a way where I can convert the weekly hours so that they have the sum of Weekly Hours - Week

Example for Jon

```
-4, 4, 0
```

Not sure how to do this and wondered if there was a global setting/sum?

Comment: If you want to do it in place it will require vba, if you want to display the answer in different cells then `=$B2 - C2`

Comment: This is weekly hours minus the amount of hours for each week. I need to find what weeks are negative (i.e overtime)

Comment: Displaying them in a new column I get #value ! in each cell

Comment: Sorry I meant 4

Comment: =$B2-C2 is giving the error